# Filed values changes unexpectedly using checkbox

Tags: php, html, laravel, character-encoding, special-characters

I have multiple checkbox and their field name but i dont know where i have done wrong the name of the field changes i am unable to find out where is the problem.

Here my screen shot when checkbox values were fine:[here is fine fields working good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qz62S.png)

And this here is screen shot there is multiple questions marks like ???? and these becoming annoying 
[this fields value are with ???? there should not any question marks in this field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2x0Rw.png)

And my form where these checkboxes value are:

```
                  <form id="preferences_form" role="form" method="POST" novalidate action="{{ url('/preference') }}" class="mujucet-registration">
                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                            <h5>Nastavení zpráv</h5>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                        <label  for="ch1">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="monthly" value="1" id="ch1"><span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon fa fa-check"></i></span>Mesícní výpisy
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                        <label >
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="weekly" value="1"><span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon fa fa-check"></i></span>Týdenní prehled
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                        <label>
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="tax_reviews" value="1"><span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon fa fa-check"></i></span>Danové výpisy
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                        <label>
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="quarterly" value="1"><span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon fa fa-check"></i></span>Ctvrtletní výpisy
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                        <label>
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="annually" value="1"><span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon fa fa-check"></i></span>Rocní výpisy
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                        <label>
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="newsletter" value="1"><span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon fa fa-check"></i></span>Novinky
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                        <label class="border">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="direct_mail_reviews" value="1"><span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon fa fa-check"></i></span> Chci výpisy zasílat také Poštou <span class="light">20 kc za výpis</span>
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div><h5>Kontaktní preference</h5>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                        <label>
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="email" value="1"><span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon fa fa-check"></i></span>Email
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                        <label>
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="sms" value="1"><span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon fa fa-check"></i></span>SMS
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>                    </div>
```

I dont how my checkboxes value goes weird here your help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

For me it looks like encoding problem. Make sure that you use same view in both cases, and in both cases you have same encoding (I assume `UTF-8`):

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

in `<head>` section of your HTML.

Also make sure the file is saved in same encoding as you declared above.

Comment: any other suitable solution please i am stuck here

Comment: If you have those values saved in HTML (you don't take them from database) I don't see any other reason why you don't have it displayed in valid way.

Comment: it was working perfectly i was working on another task i dont how its changed

Comment: its after when i add value and name attribute in input type checkbox in my form but if i removed value and name attribute it still remains same

Comment: @shahzadshah But are you sure file is saved in same encoding? Editors can save same file in multiple encodings for example UTF-8, ISO-8859-1 and so on

Comment: i dont know how to save file my file name is mujecet.blade.php

Comment: can you tell me further or show me how to save file in required format so i solved this problem i am using phpstorm

Comment: It depends on editor you use, in most of them you can save file in encoding you want.

Comment: when i changed to utf encoding it display message error loading file

Comment: currently its not 1252 ANSI - LATIN

Comment: So it means, you saved file with invalid encoding and now you should switch to UTF-8 and correct all characters manually

Comment: how to switch its giving error that error uploading file why its giving error